# How to filter length of a column part?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to filter 8Char Passwords in Notepad++

I need only 8-25 length passwords.

```
> doni@gmx.de:polli16 

> 

> 

> 
> ljjlvjljh@jhijhdhbjd.de:asdfghjkllkj
> 
nichi@dsl.de:12345678
```

How to do that with regex?

Comment: be clearer, what's the password chars requirement? what's the format of each line? etc.

Comment: ljjlvjljh@jhijhdhbjd.de:asdfghjkllkj

Comment: Please specify the desired output: do you want lines with 8 (or less ?) characters remain or do you want those line removed?

Comment: i need only 8-25 lenght passwords after : delim

Answer (score 0):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `^[^:]*:.{0,7}$\R`
- **Replace With:** `` (nothing)
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All

**Explanation:**

- we match whole lines (`^` to `$`) up to and including the newline character at the end (`\R`), (inlcuding `\R` makes the replacement also remove the empty line that would be left over otherwise)
- that have only 0 to 7 characters (`{0,7}` between the `:` and the end of line
- we use `^[^:]*:` to consume everything up to and inluding the first `:` to get to the password part of the line.